# Finding the upper bound of an increasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question asks to find the upper bound of the sequence $\left\langle\dfrac{2n-3}{3n+4}\right\rangle$. The answer I got is 2/3 as I assume upper bound is the limit as well, however the answer in my textbook says that the upper bound is 1. Could you please explain why?

Comment: The sequence has many upper bounds (for positive $n$) including 1 and 2/3. Did the question ask for the *least* upper bound?

Comment: It says to find an 'appropaiate upper bound'

Comment: Well the meaning of "appropriate" depends on the context. I agree with you that the least upper bound is $\frac{2}{3}$. But maybe $n$ is always an integer and for some reason the book wanted the least upper bound which is an integer.

Comment: So if the question was asking for the least upper bound instead, would the answer be 2/3 then?.

Comment: Yes @Waterloo97. If the book asked for that, the answer is 2/3.

Comment: An upperbound of a set $A$ is any number, call it $b$, so that $b \geq a \forall a \in A$. $1$ works just fine. It is appropriate.

Comment: @Waterloo97 I noticed that your original formula writes `<(2n-3)/(3n+4)>`. Is there some special meaning about the brackets `<…>`?